# Use HTML5 form validation and jQuery to send data to database

Tags: jquery, html, email-validation

Im looking to use HTML5 for a form for subscriptions.
Email type and required are used for the email.
I am running a jquery script when the submit is clicked to send the data to another page via ajax.
The problem is that the jquery script is still being run even if the HTML5 validation shows an error. How can i stop the script running if the error is shown.

```
<form class="subscribe" id="email" method="get">
    <input class="email" id="emailaddress" name="email" type="email" placeholder="EXAMPLE@EMAIL.COM" required>
    <input class="button" type="button" id="emailSub" value="Subscribe">
</form>

$('#emailSub').on('click', function(){
    var email = $('#emailaddress').val();
    $.ajax({
        type:"GET",
        url: "doSubscribe/",
        data: {email: email},
        success: function(result){
            $('#subResult').html(result);
        }
    });
})
```

Comment: Why not use `$('#email').submit(function(){})`? Even though your current code already works here - http://jsfiddle.net/gWKD5/1/

Comment: I dont want it to do the jquery if the html calls an error. if email is invalid "works" shouldnt appear. http://jsfiddle.net/gWKD5/3/

Comment: So did you try `$('#emailSub').on('submit'` or `$('#email').submit(function(){})`?

Comment: tired both, even changed my submit type from button to submit and back

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#email').submit(function(){
        doAjax();
        return false;
    })
    function doAjax(){
        var email = $('#emailaddress').val();
        $.ajax({
            type:"GET",
            url: "doSubscribe/",
            data: {email: email},
            success: function(result){
                $('#subResult').html(result);
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: I had used it but it wasnt working for me but after using the one you showed there it does. Maybe I had copied it wrong or something. Using it now. Thanks much :D